# Referring to individual chapters in a review of an edited volume

Tags: books

I have to write a review of an edited volume and wonder what the best approach would be to cite individual papers, to which I refer. The review is for a bulletin rather than a journal and the format is quite open. I want to give enough info that the reader can locate any chapters of interest but think that putting the full titles in the main body will take up too much space, whereas adding a reference/endnote for each chapter seems like overkill. There are 12 chapters overall and I plan to refer to most of them. The field is computer science.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask at [TeX-LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Cite them normally. At least [BibTeX](http://www.bibtex.org) has a feature to refer to another entry (the book as a whole, in this case) in the entry for the individual article, giving something like 'A. N. Author, "Random ramblings", pages 111-123 in [reference-of-the-book]' in the bibliography.

For techniques/tools for writing papers, you should perhaps ask at [TeX-LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

From [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-cite-chapter-in-book/2518#2518) to a similar question, [How to cite chapter in book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-cite-chapter-in-book), on tex.stackexchange.com:

> I think the best policy is never to talk of chapter numbers in the reflist at all, and move talk of chapter numbers, on the few occasions they are needed, to the citation in the main text. But of course you can't always choose. So, if you must use a particular Bibtex style that uses chapters, then include them in your *.bib files, and avoid Bibtex styles that allow you to refer to chapter numbers in the reference list whenever you can.